# script not present in system.web error my application upgraded from visual studio 2010 ultimate to visual studio 2017 professional

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, web-applications, visual-studio-2017

In this System.Web.Extension is present and still script error occurring showing in red line System.Web.Script.JavaScriptSerialization sdf =something is there .
pls give the solution

Comment: Did you add a reference or are you saying you have `System.Web.Extension` in a `using` statement?

Comment: System.Web.Extention is in reference only

Comment: and my controls in design are notworking in code behind